# Own encryption script

Tags: php, arrays, encryption, hash, passwords

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   $string = "123456";
   $replace_from = array(
   "1",
   "2",
   "3",
   "4",
   "5",
   "6");
   $replace_to = array(
   "Al01",
   "Br20",
   "Ch03",
   "De40",
   "Ec05",
   "Fo60");
   $hashed = str_replace($string, $replace_from, $replace_to);
   echo "String: ". $string ."<br>";
   echo "Encrypted: ". $hashed ."<br>";
   echo "<br>";
   print_r($hashed);
?>
```

I get

```
Encrypted: Array
```

But I expected

```
Encrypted: Al01Br20Ch03De40Ec05Fo60
```

How do I get hash as return?

Comment: As a side note, why are you creating your own encryption/hash function?

Comment: This type of attempt is waste of time unless you are doing this for homework or self-learning. For production you should use already established technologies

Comment: I'm very sorry, but if you get this wrong it is my opinion you cannot and should not try to create some encryption. Also I see this question is tagged [passwords] so I hope you are not going to use the above code anywhere near a production site / project.

Comment: Doing your own encryption for anything serious is wrong. Don't do it. If this is used for anything other than a learning exercise, kittens are dying.

Comment: I didn't asked if it's good idea to make it. I am asking the solution anyway... do you expect it's whole script? Offcourse not! I changed arrays...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the order of parameters to [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) wrong:

```
$hashed = str_replace( $replace_from, $replace_to, $string );
```

The correct order is

1. (Array of) strings to search for
2. (Array of) replacements
3. (Array of) strings, in which to replace

Comment: Wow, it has to be said that the PHP API differs with most API's in this regard. I see the benefits, but it would certainly wrong-foot me.